# Make CSS grid take up 1 row of another (separate) overlapping CSS grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a layout where a text introduction is inline with the first product grid item. Then rest of the product grid should then wrap below.

However, on mobile I need these items to be separate as the introduction needs to be above the product grid - which scrolls horizontally in an accordion. So the product 'cards' are wrapped in a div to contain them.

I have the majority of this working in my example, however the intro spans 2 rows of the grid (and more when more product rows are added), so if the text is longer it would go behind the project cards.

So how do I limit that grid to just taking up 1 row of the product grid? Is it possible with only CSS?

You'll need to view the example on a wider (800px+) viewport to see the desktop layout.

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}

.products {
  margin: 64px 32px;
}

.products__grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  column-gap: 4px;
  margin: 0 -32px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  scroll-padding-left: 32px;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

.product-card {
  background-color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 32px 32px 64px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.product-card__title {
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0 32px;
}

.product-card--story {
  background-color: transparent;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 32px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {

  .products {
    display: grid;
    column-gap: 4px;
    margin: 64px 32px 64px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  }

  .products__desc {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .24);
    grid-column: 2 / span 4;
    grid-row: 1;
  }


  .products__grid {
    display: grid;
    column-gap: 4px;
    row-gap: 4px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
    grid-row: 1;
    grid-column: 1 / span 12;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .product-card {
    grid-column: span 4;

    &:first-child {
      grid-column: 9 / span 4;
    }
  }

  .product-card__title {
    color: black;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 0 32px;
  }

  .product-card--story {
    background-color: transparent;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0 32px;
    text-align: center;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="products">
                
                <div class="products__desc">
                    <h2>Title of the Block</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
                        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
                        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
                        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="products__grid">
                    <a href="#" class="product-card">
                        <h3 class="product-card__title">Title of Product #1</h3>
                        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/13446290/pexels-photo-13446290.jpeg" alt="ALT TEXT" class="product-card__image"> 
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="product-card">
                        <h3 class="product-card__title">Title of Product #2</h3>    
                        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/13446290/pexels-photo-13446290.jpeg" alt="ALT TEXT" class="product-card__image">
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="product-card">
                        <h3 class="product-card__title">Title of Product #3</h3>
                        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/13446290/pexels-photo-13446290.jpeg" alt="ALT TEXT" class="product-card__image">
                    </a>    
                    <div class="product-card product-card--story">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be a more elegant way to do this, but the problem seems to be breaking out of the scroller grid and place the item into the main grid. Not sure if thats possible. So my workaround is quite simple: double the first product, hide up the top one on mobile and hide it in the scroller on desktop.

```css
.description {
        background: red;
        padding: 24px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      .scroller {
        background: yellow;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        gap: 12px;
        max-width: 100%;
      }

      .product {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 24px;
        background: cyan;
        flex-shrink: 0;
      }

      .products > .first {
        display: none;
      }

      .first {
        background: greenyellow;
      }

      @media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
        .products {
          display: grid;
          grid-template-areas:
            "a b"
            "c c";
          grid-template-columns: auto 400px;
          gap: 12px;
        }

        .description {
          grid-area: a;
          height: 400px;
        }

        .products > .first {
          grid-area: b;
          display: block;
          background: pink;
        }

        .scroller {
          grid-area: c;
        }
      }
```

```html
    <div class="products">
      <div class="description">Description</div>
      <div class="product first">product 1a</div>
      <div class="scroller">
        <div class="product first">product 1b</div>
        <div class="product">product 2</div>
        <div class="product">product 3</div>
        <div class="product">product 4</div>
        <div class="product">product 5</div>
        <div class="product">product 6</div>
        <div class="product">product 7</div>
        <div class="product">product 8</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Another option - without doubling content - is to pull the first product out of the scroller by positioning it absolute. This has its drawbacks though as you need to set the description width and height relative to the size of the content block of the product, otherwise your first product will overlap with the description.

```css
  .description {
        background: red;
        padding: 24px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      .scroller {
        background: yellow;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        gap: 12px;
      }

      .product {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 24px;
        background: cyan;
        flex-shrink: 0;
      }

      .first {
        background: greenyellow;
      }

      @media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
        .products {
          position: relative;
        }

        .description {
          grid-area: a;
          height: 400px;
        }

        .first {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          right: 0;
          background: pink;
        }
      }
```

```html
 <div class="products">
      <div class="description">Description</div>
      <div class="scroller">
        <div class="product first">product 1</div>
        <div class="product">product 2</div>
        <div class="product">product 3</div>
        <div class="product">product 4</div>
        <div class="product">product 5</div>
        <div class="product">product 6</div>
        <div class="product">product 7</div>
        <div class="product">product 8</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the examples! Yeah I'm not sure there's an obvious 'organic' solution so compromising and having the first product in a grid might be the way to go. Or maybe having them all in one div. Then adding/removing the wrapping div around the 'carousel' on mobile with JS another